# Stopping never ending append. jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to set it up so that it checks to see if it has another variable, and if it doesn't, add it.

```
var item = "<li>Testing</li>";
var hasItem = $(".target-class").has(item).length;
if(hasItem == 0) {$(".target-class").append(item)}
```

This doesn't work and it keeps appending item forever.

Comment: Once you fixed your typo I see nothing wrong with the code. Please post a complete code example and a jsFiddle.net example if possible.

Comment: agree with @j08691. There must be a loop somewhere that you're not showing us.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sp2T7/ Supposed to add a fourth item in the result window.

Comment: `var badge = "<li Testing /li>";` in your fiddle looks very wrong. Also you didn't include jQuery. Without jQuery it obvisously doesn't work at all.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sp2T7/4/ Didn't know that updates went to a new url. This is a plugin, it will automatically include jQuery when you run it.

Comment: No, you have to configure jsFiddle to include jQuery. Your update throws the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined `. Why? Because you don't include jQuery. Instead of "No-Library (pure JS)" select one of the jQuery versions.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sp2T7/5/

Comment: Yep. And if you now apply the solution in my answer, it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually had

```
var hasItem = $(".target-class").has(item).length;
```

messed up. It wasn't selecting what I thought it was selecting. As a tip for anyone new to jQuery, add .remove() to the end of your selector. When you are removing exactly what you want to select then you know you have it right. Just remove .remove() and you are good to go.
Along with fixing .has(item), it now works.

Answer (score 1):

`.has` expects a selector, not HTML:

```
var item = '<li class="testing">Testing</li>';
var hasItem = $(".target-class").has('li.testing').length;
```

Please read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/has/).

Answer (score 0):

So if your HTML were:

```
<div class="target-class"></div>
```

Then the below `while` loop would add the `div` element once and then stop executing:

```
var item = "<li class='testing'>Testing</li>";
var targetEl = $(".target-class");
while (!targetEl.has("li.testing").length) {targetEl.append(item);}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cssimsek/qdpFJ/